# Visio - How to ungroup shapes but keep the same names?

Tags: vba, shapes, visio

I'm working on Visio  (I didn't to the file) and all the shapes are grouped, there is only one shape by group and when I ungroup all the shapes all the names are modified and replaced by random names like "sheet.8331" , do you know if there is a way to ungroup all the shapes without modifying the names of shapes ? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Why do you want to ungroup?

Answer (score 1):

You could read the names prior to ungrouping (VBA), but it is generally a bad idea to use names.

You better rely on fields in the user section to identify shapes.

eg: user.MyIdentificator = "It's me!"

Retrieving the shape is as easy as:

```
for each shp in activepage.shapes (or in parent_shape)
  if shp.cellexists("user.MyIdentificator", visExistsAnywhere) then
    if shp.cells("user.MyIdentificator").ResultStr("") = "It's me!" then
      'do your stuff
... closing ifs and loops
```

HTH,

Comment: thanks for your answer :) , I had find another solution eventually

Answer (score 1):

I suspect GG made a "shape" that was a set of shapes, then dragged them onto a stencil.

You may not need to ungroup, as there is a way to "go inside of the group" and make changes. Many users that are destroying things by ungrouping are unaware of "group-editing windows".

Just right-click any group, then choose **Group > Open Group**, or **Group > Open SomeName**.

---

I'll add some more technical mumbo-jumbo that may help other readers who find their way to this thread.

When the newly-created master is dragged back into a drawing, Visio groups the shapes together. This is to preserve the inheritance that Visio establishes between the local master (stored in the Document Stencil of the drawing file) and each instance of the master on the pages of the document.

The inheritance is a way of saving data---shapes on pages aren't all copies of their original masters, then *inherit* the properties of masters. Only bits that the user changes, such as location, size, text, etc. are overridden. This inheritance can be a powerful tool, can save on file size, but can also be confusing.

When you ungroup the master, you sever it's link to the master, and the shapes become new copies with no inheritance. Visio has to give them names. I'm not sure why your original names are lost. I would think you would end up with a bunch of names that look like "NameOriginal.3", "NameOriginal.46", etc. That's what happens in my tests.

Anyway, names must be unique "at scope" - meaning at the same level of grouping. So for shapes just sitting on the page, there can only be one "Bob". If you make a copy of "Bob", he'll be "Bob.46" or something.

I can have 7000 groups that each have a subshape named "Bob", since each "Bob" exists in its own unique scope--the group shields one Bob from another. But all of those Bobs will have unique "SheetID" indices. Those can be used for doing cross-sheet formula references in the ShapeSheet.